# Which metric to use to make the sequence 1, 1.4, 1.414, 1.4142, .. converges in space Q?

Tags: convergence-divergence, metric-spaces

In space Q, with the metric it inherits from R, the sequence 1, 1.4, 1.414, 1.4142, ... does not converge.

Is there a way to change the metric to make it converge in Q?

Comment: You can use the indiscrete metric.(always $0$)

Comment: It is not a metric. Does not satisfy $d(x,y)=0 \iff x=y$.

Comment: Technically the pseudometric.

Comment: Converge to what?  What *is* the sequence?  I'm assuming it is the finite decimal expansion such that q_n^2 < 2.  But that assuming it's defined via the euclidean norm.  If it's converging to some rational q then we need a norm where |root 2 - q_n$|_{euc} $ < e. implies |q - q$|_{new}$ < e and that's going to be ... difficult.

Answer (score 2):

On $\mathbb{Z}_{+}\cup\{\perp\}$ define metric
$$d'(x,y)=\begin{cases} |1/x-1/y| & \mbox{if } x,y\in\mathbb{Z}_+ \\ 
1/x & \mbox{if } x\in\mathbb{Z}_+, \ y=\perp \\
1/y & \mbox{if } x=\perp, \ y\in\mathbb{Z}_+ \\
0 & \mbox{if } x=y=\perp \end{cases}$$.

Let $f:\mathbb{Q}\to\mathbb{Z}_{+}\cup\{\perp\}$ be an arbitrary bijection.
Finally for $x,y\in\mathbb{Q}$ let $d(x,y)=d'(f(x),f(y))$. Now let $(x_n)_n$ be any $1-1$ sequence of rational numbers, then $d(x_n,f^{-1}(\perp)) = d'(f(x_n),\perp)=1/f(x_n)\to 0$, since $f(x_n)\to\infty$ as a $1-1$ sequence of positive natural numbers.

Answer (score 1):

On any set $C=A\cup B$, where $A\ne \phi=A\cap B$ and $B=\{f(n) :n \in N\}$ where $f$ is a bijection,we can define a metric $d$ on $C$ such that $(f(n))_{n\in N}$ converges to some $a\in A$ , thusly: Choose $a\in A.$ Let $d(a,f(n))=2^{-n},$ let $ d(f(m),f(n))=|2^{_m}-2^{-n}|$, and let $d(c_1,c_2)=1$ whenever $c_1\ne c_2$ and  at least one of $c_1,c_2$ belongs to $A\backslash \{a\}.$